# get certain date, preventing holidays or sundays stored on database

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

i have column datetime format with consecutive dates, but i need count 60 days ago from now but i need prevent days marked with 0 because days are sundays or holidays.

this not work:

```
SELECT DateDVH as refDays 
FROM DVH_days 
WHERE DateDVH>'2016-12-20 00:00:00' 
AND (DateDVH_dia<'2017-02-18 00:00:00' + INTERVAL 60 DAY) 
AND DateDVH_daytype!=0
```

`DateDVH_daytype=0` is holidays and sundays.

It is possible to place a counter in the query or a condition that prevents the days type = 0 or a stored procedure??

**update**
i solve it with :

```
SELECT DateDVH_dia 
FROM Avipac_DVH_dias 
WHERE DateDVH_dia>now() 
AND DateDVH_diatype!=0 
LIMIT 60
```

but i get a list of 60 date and only need get the last date

Comment: When `DateDVH_daytype` is zero is it really zero or is it NULL? If its NULL or could be NULL use also `AND DateDVH_daytype IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Sorry for the writing error, I just want to get the last record or date.

Comment: `ORDER BY DateDVH_dia ASC LIMIT 1` or maybe `ORDER BY DateDVH_dia DESC LIMIT 1` not sure what you really want anymore

Comment: really zero=0 or 1 not null default is 1, Sorry for the writing error, I just want to get the last record or date.

Comment: ASC LIMIT 1 or DESC LIMIT 1 cant be used becouse i use Limit 60 to count last 60 registre but i need filter one more time the last registry... to get one registry only